# MUI custom theme doesn't override palette

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to do a simple test of overriding the default theme in MUI before applying it to a larger project.  After following the docs I can't get the new colors I've applied in my theme to take effect in a child component.

I'm using MUI 5 with React 18 built with Vite.  The default colors I'm trying to override are palette.success, palette.warning and palette.error.  I have followed [these docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/) and triple-checked for mistakes but cannot figure out what I'm missing or where I've gone wrong.  None of the color choices I have in my theme below are being applied in the component where I use them.

**main.tsx**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { green, red, yellow } from '@mui/material/colors';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        success: {
            main: green[300]
        },
        warning: {
            main: yellow[400]
        },
        error: {
            main: red[800]
        }
    },

});


root.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Outlet, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import RootLayout from './components/RootLayout';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import ManageFeeds from './components/ManageFeeds';
import EditFeed from './components/EditFeed';
import { UserFeed } from './models';

function App(props: any) {

    const [userFeeds, setUserFeeds] = useState<UserFeed[]>();
    const appService = new AppService();

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
                    <Route path="" element={<HomePage appService={appService}/>} />
                    <Route path="feeds" element={<Outlet />}>
                        <Route path="manage" element={<ManageFeeds userFeeds={userFeeds} />} />
                        <Route path="edit" element={<EditFeed userFeeds={userFeeds} /> } />
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**HomePage.tsx**
Here all I'm doing as a test is rendering three chips, each with the palette color I specified in my theme.

```
import { Box, Chip } from '@mui/material';

export default function HomePage(props: any) {

    return (
        <Box sx={{ height: 1 }}>
            <Chip color='success' label="success" />
            <Chip color='warning' label="neutral" />
            <Chip color='error' label="negative" />
        </Box>
    )
}
```

The above code renders these chips in the default colors:

[image]

What I expected to see was these colors:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: After copying and testing your code locally on my device, it's working fine for me. Maybe try installing the latest version of mui.

Comment: @SimranSingh Thanks for your help.  It helped me to know that someone else got it working.  Eventually I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be a second **ThemeProvider** element wrapping the entire JSX returned by the RootLayout component.  If I hadn't neglected to include it in my codes snippets above I'm sure someone would have spotted it before I did.

I had this:

```
 return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={globalTheme}>
            <Box sx={{ height: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <Outlet/>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
 )
```

So I was setting my custom theme in main.tsx correctly but it was being overwritten by the global theme being set in RootLayout.  Stupid mistake!